# tight bounds for $(1-x)^{1/x}$ for $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: inequality, approximation

It is well known that $0\le (1-x)^{1/x}\le exp(-1)$ for $x\in[0,1]$. However, are there tighter upper and lower bounds that also capture the rate by which the value drops w.r.t $x$?

Comment: Do you mean "Is there a function $x \mapsto f(x)$ with the property that for $x \in [0,1],$ we have $0 \le (1-x)^{\frac{1}[x} \le f(x)$"? I mean, the question gives an example, namely $f(x) = \exp(-1)$. And there's the obvious optimal answer $f(x) =  (1-x)^{\frac{1}[x}$. Can you be little more specific about what would be a "good" answer? Right now, this isn't a math question, it's a reading-your-mind question.

Comment: You could also use the tangent line at $0$, i.e. $f(x) = \exp(-1) + x h'(0)$, where $h(x) = (1-x)^{1/x}$, and I don't feel like explicitly calculating the derivative myself.

Comment: Take logarithm to get $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}=-1-\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4-\cdots$ and now you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FengShao points out, 
$$
\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}=-1-\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4-\cdots
$$
which means that (taking $\exp$ of both sides)
$$
(1-x)^{1/x} = \exp\left(-1-\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4-\cdots \right)
$$
Now because $\exp$ is an increasing function, and all the terms involving $x$ are negative, we can further write
$$
(1-x)^{1/x} = \exp\left(-1-\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4-\cdots \right) \le \exp(-1),
$$
which is your known bound. But we can do better. Because *each* term involving $x$ is nonnegative, we can also say that 
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{1/x} &\le\exp\left(-1-\frac{x}2\right)\\
(1-x)^{1/x} &\le\exp\left(-1-\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}3\right)\\
(1-x)^{1/x} &\le\exp\left(-1-\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4\right)\\
\end{align}
a sequence of upper bounds that converges, in the limit, to my trivial upper bound. Away from $x = 0$, each of these bounds can also be replaced by a strict inequality (i.e., on the interval $0 < x < 1$).